# Firebase instruct me to put two A records, but it only gave me one

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, namecheap

here's from [firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) :

> Return to your domain name provider's DNS management site to create DNS A records pointing your page to Firebase Hosting. Add and save records with the following inputs:
>
> 1. Type: Add two DNS A records.

but it only gave me one IP Address:[image: Firebase Screenshot]

I **have** added the A record on my domain registrar and waited 24 hours. It has not worked.
I tried making two A records with the same IP address, but the registrar ignores it and consider it one.
I'm using Namecheap.
I expect Firebase to give me two A records like it's supposed to.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. It looks like you already have the answer you need, but in the future please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is out of date in this case (I'll file a note to get that fixed) - one IP address is all Firebase Hosting provides and all that is required.

If you added the record correctly but it's still not working, I'd recommend reaching out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) for more detailed troubleshooting of your specific case.